# Deleting first node in linked list after the rest has be deleted

Tags: algorithm, singly-linked-list

I have to implement a linked list in the form of a bag. Usually, bags don't have remove but in this case I need one.

When I run my test client, and I call remove, all instances of that item in my linked list is deleted, except for the very first value.

So essentially my output looks like this:

```
removed all 9s: 4 4 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 4 4 3 3 2 2 1 1 
removed all 3s: 4 4 4 4 4 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 4 4 2 2 1 1 
removed all 1s: 4 4 4 4 4 2 2 2 2 2 4 4 2 2
removed all 4s: 4 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 
removed all 2s: 4
```

Here is my code:

```
public void remove (int item)
{
  // TODO
  Node previous = null; 
  Node current = first;

  if (first == null) // list is empty do nothing
  {
  }
  else if (first.item == item) // item occurs in first node 
  {
    //previous = first;
    first = first.next;
  } // skip around first node
  else
  {
    // find the node before item                                            
    for (Node p = first.next, q = first; p != null; q = p, p = q.next)
    {
      if (p.item == item)
      {
        q.next = p.next;
        //p.next = q.next;
        //return;            
      }
    }
  }

  while (current != null)
  {
    if(current.item == item)
    {
      current = current.next;            
      if (previous == null)
        previous = current;
      else
        previous.next = current;
    }
    else
    {
      previous = current;
      current = current.next;
    }
  } //end while
  //return;
}
```

Here is the test client code:

```
b1.remove(9);
print ("removed all 9s", b1); // does nothing
b1.remove(3);

print ("removed all 3s", b1);
b1.remove(1);

print ("removed all 1s", b1);
b1.remove(4);

print ("removed all 4s", b1);
b1.remove(2);

print ("removed all 2s", b1); // should be empty
```

Can someone help me figure out why that 4 remains after it was supposed to have been deleted?

Comment: In else if condition, you are skipping first node and then start removing the node items. So you never delete the first node.

Comment: I thought by saying first = first.next, that the deletion was being done?

Comment: Ya you are right. It is not deleted from memory but solving the purpose. I was actually confused why you unnecessarily did this. I got your intentions now. There should be some other problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is in the line

```
if (previous == null){previous = current;}
```

First three items are 4.
On remove(4), steps followed are
`first = first.next` //First points to 2nd item 4 but current still points to first item 4.
`if(current.item == item) current = current.next` //Now current also points to second 4.
`previous = current` // Since previous is null, so if statement will be true, previous also point to second 4.

In furthur while loops, previous is not null and you are assigning current to previous.next. So you never skipped second 4.

**UPDATE**:
Say you have a node `head` pointing to a dummy node following by other nodes.

```
remove(item)
{
    previous = head;
    current = head.next;
    while(current!=null)
    {
        if(current.item == item)
        {
            previous.next = current.next;
            current = current.next;
        }
        else
        {
            previous = current;
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So how would I get it to point to the first 4? Do I place a Node before first to point to the first item 4?

Comment: Its always a better and safe idea to start with a dummy node and make it point to first significant node. I suggest you to do so.

Comment: Perhaps I'm still a tiny bit confused. It makes sense in my head but I cant seem to implement.

Comment: I tried making a node called temp assigning current to it. essentially, temp.next = current; and I basically said if temp.next.item is equal to item, the temp = temp.next. still same result

Comment: I have updated with some rough code. First node points to dummy node.

Comment: Aww sorry, this is my first question post. I'm such a noob!